# Matlab regexp split time array and save time output for plotting

Tags: matlab, sorting, time, delimiter

I'm trying to loop through an array of dates/times in matlab, split each column using regexp with the following delimiters ('/' or ':' or '.'), and store each column separately as year, day, hour, min, sec, ss, respectively.  Ultimately I'm trying to turn this array of Julian dates and times into a **plot**-able format in matlab.  So far I've been able to loop through my array called 'time' and created a new 1x6 cell called 'clean2_time' which splits each row into 6 columns (year, day, hour, min, sec, ss) based on the delimiters '/' ':' and '.'.  My issue is that the loop overwrites 'clean2_time' every iteration and I am left with only the final 1x6 time stamp for the last row.  I have tried creating a new variable of all zeros 'z' and setting 'clean2_time' equal to z but have no luck.

Sample of 'time':

```
'2013/231/21:38:09.856619'
'2013/231/21:38:09.955640'
'2013/231/21:38:10.156685'
'2013/231/21:38:10.356550'
'2013/231/21:38:10.556770'
'2013/231/21:38:10.756565'
'2013/231/21:38:10.955627'
'2013/231/21:38:11.256588'
'2013/231/21:38:11.556649'
'2013/231/21:38:11.955597'
'2013/231/21:38:12.356627'
'2013/231/21:38:12.856557'
'2013/231/21:38:13.356558'
'2013/231/21:38:14.156530'
'2013/231/21:38:14.970500'
'2013/231/21:38:16.256545'
'2013/231/21:38:16.266736'
'2013/231/21:38:18.156398'
```

Code I've tried so far:

```
z=zeros(size(time,1),6);
for i = 1:size(time,1)  % for i = 1 to 5922
    clean2_time = regexp(time{i,1}, '[/:.]', 'split');
    z{i,1} = clean2_time(i,1)
    z{i,2} = clean2_time(i,2)
    z{i,3} = clean2_time(i,3)
    z{i,4} = clean2_time(i,4)
    z{i,5} = clean2_time(i,5)
    z{i,6} = clean2_time(i,6)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
clean2_time=zeros(size(time,1),6);
for i = 1:size(time,1)  % for i = 1 to 5922
    clean2_time(i,:)=regexp(time{i,1}, '[/:.]', 'split')
end
```

`clean2_time(i,:)` indexes the i-th row of the cell.

Comment: You can remove the first line. `z` is not necessary for your solution. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track, however, you don't need the `for` loop.

Simply doing this would suffice:

```
clean2_time=regexp(time, '[/:.]', 'split');
```

Then `clean2_time` is a cell structure in which every row contains another 1x6 cell array. You can then access the different values with: `clean2_time{row}{column}`. If you really want `clean2_time` to be a nx6 numerical matrix instead of this cell array of strings, simply use this to reshape:

```
clean2_time=cellfun(@str2num,vertcat(clean2_time{:}))
```

Comment: This is great, but I just noticed that 'clean2_time=cellfun(@str2num,vertcat(clean2_time{:}))' deletes the last zero in the microsecond column if there is one.  This will not work since I ultimately want to plot this date/time.  Could you help me understand how I should plot this?

Comment: This is not the case for me. With your provided data all the lines ending on a zero, still end on a zero for me.

Comment: I'm sorry you're right, it's the leading zero in the microsecond column that is removed which makes sense because you're converting to a number.  This will cause the times to be incorrect when plotting.  Any ideas how to get around this?  I could remove the '.' as one of the delimiters and that might work.  Any ideas on how to plot the Julian calendar day (example 2013/231 = August 19th, 2013) ?

Comment: Okay, so if you want to keep it as a string instead of a number, just replace `clean2_time=cellfun(@str2num,vertcat(clean2_time{:}))` with `clean2_time=vertcat(clean2_time{:})`, and use {} brackets for indexing.